# Notepad++ or Vim Document Wrap or Text File Wrap

Tags: vim, notepad++, regex

This is going to sound weird, bear with me. I am **not** looking for the regular word wrap, which I already know how to toggle.

Is there any possibility to do a "document wrap" or "text wrap" in Notepad++? Example, imagine a text file with three long lines (line number at beginning):

```
1 A 111111111 222222222 333333333 444444444 555555555 666666666 777777777 888888888 999999999 000000000 aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeeee fffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkk
2 B 111111111 222222222 333333333 444444444 555555555 666666666 777777777 888888888 999999999 000000000 aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeeee fffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkk
3 C 111111111 222222222 333333333 444444444 555555555 666666666 777777777 888888888 999999999 000000000 aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeeee fffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkk
```

A "document wrapped" version would look like this:

```
1 A 111111111 222222222 333333333 444444444 555555555 666666666 777777777 8888
2 B 111111111 222222222 333333333 444444444 555555555 666666666 777777777 8888
3 C 111111111 222222222 333333333 444444444 555555555 666666666 777777777 8888
<wrapped>
1 88888 999999999 000000000 aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeeee 
2 88888 999999999 000000000 aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeeee 
3 88888 999999999 000000000 aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeeee 
<wrapped>
1 fffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkk
2 fffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkk
3 fffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh iiiiiiiii jjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkk
```

Best is to have Notepad++ automatically do and undo it (similar to Word Wrap toggle). However, we can also use a solution that permanently modifies the file content - perhaps using a regex to cut the excess of lines exceeding a column number, and paste them at the bottom of file.

I can also try a `vim` feature if any.

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way to do this. But both editors have scripting capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following in your [vimrc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimrc), then press <kbd>F12</kbd> to use.  Press <kbd>u</kbd> to undo the changes.

```
nmap <F12> :call FileWrapOuter()<CR>

function! FileWrapOuter()
    while FileWrap()
    endwhile
endfunction

function! FileWrap()
    " Go to end of file and set mark 'a'.
    norm G
    norm ma
    let w:madeChange = 0
    " Call FileWrapInner() for each long line.
    :%g/.\{80\}/call FileWrapInner()
    if w:madeChange
        " Return to mark 'a' and add <wrapped>.
        norm 'a
        norm o<wrapped>
        return 1
    endif
    return 0
endfunction

function! FileWrapInner()
    " Copy current line into 't' buffer.
    norm "tyy
    " Delete anything in line after 79th character.
    norm 0
    norm 79l
    norm d$
    " Paste 't' buffer at end of file.
    norm G
    norm "tp
    " Delete first 79 characters.
    norm 0
    norm 79x
    let w:madeChange = 1
endfunction
```

This assumes a maximum width of 79 characters.  For other amounts, change occurrences of `80` and `79` in the functions above.